# How can write a class hierarchy to easily switch between floating-point types?

Tags: c++, templates, floating-point, typedef

In my 3d graphics program, I can write my classes to use either `float` or `double` to represent real numbers. I want to be able to easily make the choice at compile-time. I see two options:

1) Change all classes into templates which take the floating point type as an argument. Almost all of my classes will need to be changed to templates.

2) Create a typedef (e.g. `typedef float real;`) and then make sure I use only `real` throughout my classes.

I am now at a point at which I can make both changes to my existing code. Is there any existing idiom for doing this, or do you see anything wrong with either of the choices above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one or several guides for that: use the typedef.

Standards like the MISRA C++ Coding Standard define an advisory rule for that (Rule 3-9-2)

> *typedefs* that indicate size and signedness should be used in place
>   of the basic numerical types

There might be other standards hinting the same behaviour. Afaik Win API uses typedefs (WORD, DWORD, etc) to do this.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, templates are overkill for this situation (longer compilation?), a typedef is sufficient and also preserves type-safety and readability.

The GLM Maths library also chose typedefs, for example:
[GLM Repository](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/0.9.5/glm/detail/type_float.hpp)